# Валидация файла при обновлении yii

Tags: php, yii, валидация

У меня возникла трудность: при обновлении пользователю обязательно нужно загрузить заново файл, при этом старый удалится, а имя нового запишется в базу данных.
Но чтобы изменить какую-либо информацию приходится заново загружать файл, что довольно неудобно.
В модели стоит обязательная загрузка файла:

```
array('filename', 'file', 'types'=>'rar, zip, 7z','allowEmpty'=>false,'maxFiles' => 1,'message'=>'Допустимые типы к загрузке: rar, zip, 7z'),
```

Как сделать, чтобы если файл не выбран, то запись файла не производилась бы, и наоборот соответственно?

Update (код контрллера):

```
$model=$this->loadModel($id);
                $model->scenario='update';
                if(isset($_POST['ModsManage']))
                {
                    $set_info = ModsManage::model()->findByPk($id);
                    $model->attributes=$_POST['ModsManage'];
                    if(CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'filename')){
                        $model->filename = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'filename');
                    }else{
                        $model->filename = $set_info->filename; 
                    }
                    if($model->save()){
                        if(CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'filename')){
                            if(file_exists(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/mods/'.$model->id.'/'.$set_info->filename)){
                                unlink(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/mods/'.$model->id.'/'.$set_info->filename);
                            }
                            $path=Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/mods/'.$model->id.'/'.$model->filename->getName();
                            $model->filename->saveAs($path);
                        }
                        //$this->redirect(array('mod','id'=>$model->id));
                    }
                }

                $this->render('update',array(
                    'model'=>$model,
                ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько понимаю, вам нужно реализовать две вещи:

1. Поставить `allowEmpty => true` в правилах валидации. Это позволит свалидировать модель без загруженного файла.
2. Реализовать логику сохранения, которая не будет записывать поле файла, если оно пустое. Без дополнительного кода сложно сказать, как именно это сделать, но проще всего просто не перезаписывать поле загруженной модели.

Comment: array('filename', 'file', 'types'=>'rar, zip, 7z','allowEmpty'=>false,'maxFiles' => 1,'message'=>'Допустимые типы к загрузке: rar, zip, 7z', 'on'=>'create'), 
    array('filename', 'file', 'types'=>'rar, zip, 7z','allowEmpty'=>true,'maxFiles' => 1,'message'=>'Допустимые типы к загрузке: rar, zip, 7z', 'on'=>'update'), 
и в контроллере вызываю нужные сценарии, в update делаю проверку загружен ли файл, но если файл не загружен, делаю $model->filename = $set_info->filename; дальше идёт save() но почему записывает пусто поле. При обновлении с файлом всё отлично

Comment: что такое set_info?

Comment: $set_info = ModsManage::model()->findByPk($id);
получает то, что уже записано (исп. для удаления старого файла, если новый загружен)

Comment: @innot20 проверьте, что в правилах валидации стоит safe для поля filename